# Having trouble debugging a Java/DB error where data is being put into wrong record

Tags: java, oracle, jakarta-ee, thread-safety, weblogic

This happens very infrequently and I am unable to reproduce the problem because of it.  We are running a Jave EE web app on Weblogic with an Oracle backend.  We store PDF records in the database as blobs.  What is happening is that sometimes--very rarely--when a PDF blob is being saved, it is being saved into the wrong user's row.  Now not only has the original user's PDF not been saved, but another user's PDF has been overwritten with the wrong information! A stored procedure is called to update/insert into the table.

Does it seem like this might be a session-related error? All records in the PDF table have a unique ID that serves as the primary key.  The PK is referenced when adding or updating a row in the PDF table.  What can I do to make this operation more thread-safe? I assume this is happening because multiple users are updating at the same time and somehow the UIDs get mixed up.  But like I said, it happens rarely and I haven't been able to reproduce it or find an easy solution while looking at the source code.  Am I on the right track?  Any suggestions?

Comment: It's the hallmark of a thread safety issue.  You have mutable, shared data that isn't synchronized.  You need to look at the object that's creating and inserting the PDF to fix it.